# Evaluate:$\int_{l}(4z^2-2iz)dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Evaluate:
>   $\displaystyle=\int_{l}(4z^2-2iz)dz\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,l:y=x^3+2x^2-2x$ between the points $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$

My try:

$$\int_{l}(4z^2-2iz)dz=\int_{0}^{1+i}(4z^2-2iz)dz=\frac{4z^3}{3}-\frac{2iz^2}{2}\bigg|_0^{1+i}=\frac{8i}3-\frac 2 3$$

[image]

> correct?

Comment: Yes. But you use that a polynomial is homomorphic, a closed curve, etc... This justification must be write :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that, given that your function is holomorphic everywhere, you can choose your contour to be *anything* you want it to be. For example, you might find a straight line between the two points easiest, or maybe go along the $x$-axis then vertically. This is because *any* closed contour will give $0$ integral when the integrand is holomorphic.

I'd probably try first of all just setting $z = r e^{i\pi/4}$, ie the straight line between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. If this gives then same result as what you've done, then this will verify what you have done holds (in this case at least). (I'm pretty sure that what you've done is fine, just for some reason I'm slightly uneasy about it, so don't want to confirm/deny completely!)